# Radical extension and cubic

Tags: cubics, galois-extensions

Let $P \in K[X]$ be an irreducible cubic polynomial where $K \subset \mathbb C$ and $\alpha$ a root of $P$ and one suppose $K[\alpha]$ is a radical extension of $K$.

Because $[K[\alpha]:K]=3$ ($3$ is prime, so no intermediate field)  there exist $\beta \in K[\alpha]-K$ such as $\beta^t \in K$ (with $t$ prime) and $K[\beta]=K[\alpha]$.

Of course $t\geq 3$, but, why $t=3$?

Often, some say it's obvious , because  $[K[\beta]:K]=t$, but why degree of $\beta$ would be $t$ ($i^6=1$ and degree of $i$ is $2$, not $6$).

Let $D$ the discriminant of $P$.
I
If $D$ is a square in $K$, $K[\alpha]$ is not a splitting field of $P$ and $K[\alpha]$ is not Galois over $K$ and $t=3$ ( lemma 2.3b of Isaacs and Moulton, Real fields and Repeated radical extensions, journal of algebra 201, 1998).

But if $D$ is not a square in $K$?

In this case, $K[\alpha]$ is Galois over K, so I can't apply this lemma 2.3b  and the 2.3a say only "$K[\alpha]$  contains some roots of unity different from $\pm 1$".

However, if $D$ is a square and $j$ ($j^3=1,j \neq 1$), then $-3D$ is a square in $K$ and we have one $\beta$ with $t=3$.

But, if $D$ is a square, $j$ not in $K$ ??

Note :  if $D$ is a square and $[K:\mathbb Q]$ is odd, then $K[\beta]$ is not a radical extension of $K$.
Thanks.

Comment: Note that $\beta$ is specially picked to have $\beta^3\in K$. One might ask why such a $\beta$ has to exist, but asking how we know $3$ is the correct exponent is misunderstanding where $\beta$ comes from.

Comment: @Arthur : lemma2.1 of Isaacs and Moulton  : suppose $[K[\beta]:K]=d, \beta^n \in K$....in particular, if $K$ contains all $n$th roots of unity in $K[\beta]$  then  $\beta^d \in K$

Comment: Well, $\Bbb Q[2+i]$ contains all fourth roots of unity over $\Bbb Q$, yet no integer power of $2+i$ is in $\Bbb Q$. You have to note that $\Bbb Q[2+i]$ is the same as $\Bbb Q[i]$, and then specifically pick $\beta=i$.

Comment: ?you use the lemma of Isaacs with $\beta =2+i$ (so $d=2$) but the hypothesis there exist $n$ such as $\beta^n \in \mathbb{Q}$ is not true??
I have quote this lemma to show I am not alone to think that $[K[\beta]:K]=d$ and $\beta^n \in K$ do not implies always $\beta^d \in K$ : in fact, Isaacs prove that $\epsilon \beta^d \in K$ with $\epsilon$ $n$th root of units in $K(\beta)$, without say that $\epsilon$ is always in $K$

Comment: The statement
If  $K \subset \mathbb{C}$ ,  $[K[\alpha]:K]=3$ ,  $K[\alpha]$ is a radical extension of $K$
then
there exists $\beta \in K[\alpha]-K$ such as $\beta^3\in K$
is false
because I have  an counterexample.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that. An extension with no such $\beta$ can't be radical, by definition.

Comment: One can see this radical extension (counterexample) in many documents on Galois ( idea : $i\sqrt{7}$) , but there exist no $\beta$ such as...because the discriminant is a square and $j$ is not in $K$

Comment: But in this case, we do indeed have $(i\sqrt7)^2\in \Bbb Q$, so $\Bbb Q(i\sqrt7)/\Bbb Q$ does indeed have such a $\beta$. In fact, there _must_ be such a $\beta$, because the very definition of "radical extension" says there must be.

Comment: It is the radical extension ( degree 3) $K=\mathbb{Q} (i\sqrt{7}) \subset K(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(\xi_7)$   and there is no $\beta \in K[\alpha]-K$ such as $\beta^3\in K$ : I have two proofs.
$\alpha$ is a sum of $\xi_7^i$

Comment: You know what, all this time I've been thinking about _simple_ radical extensions. Yes, I agree that non-simple radical extensions could exist. My bad.

Comment: Ok 
Now, why not this question :
I suppose $[K[\alpha] : K]=3$ with $D$ a square in $K$, $j \notin K$, so there is no $\beta \in K[\alpha]-K$ such as $\beta^3\in K$ ( because $-3D$ is not a square in $K$)
In the case one can have $K \subset K[\alpha]$ radical extension (see counterexample above).
Does it exist other cases?(I think, if $K=\mathbb{Q}(a)$, it is necessary that  $[K :\mathbb{Q} ]$ be even  ( like $a=i\sqrt7$)